# Finding what page caused a HTTP Error Response in Custom Error Page

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a website and I'm looking into setting up some form of alert, should my 404 error page or 5xx error page be accessed, so I can then fix the issue quickly.

I have the following in my .htaccess file

`ErrorDocument 404 "http://www.example.com/404_not_found.php"`

So if I go `http://www.example.com/my_page_that_doesn_t_exist.html` I'll then be redirected to `http://example.com/404_not_found.php`.

This part is working but I want to add some code to the 404_not_found.php page that can alert me, but is there a way I can get A. the specific status code that triggered the redirect and B. what URL was used to trigger the redirect.

So for example in my alert, I can say it was HTTP STatus Code 404 and path was `http://example.com/my_page_that_doesn_t_exist.html`

Comment: I used to do this in the past but I always implemented the functionality in PHP, where `$_SERVER` contains all the information I need and (more important) it's easy to filter out external links and most bogus requests (which come in hordes, trust me).

Comment: I did wonder that, I'd probably primarily want it for actual server error codes like 5xx I'll have a look at $_SERVER see what I find in there

Answer (score 0):

Apache documentation:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/custom-error.html

You can see: Available Variables

And:

> where the action will be treated as:
>
> A local URL to redirect to (if the action begins with a "/").
>       An external URL to redirect to (if the action is a valid URL).
>       Text to be displayed (if none of the above). The text must be wrapped in quotes (") if it consists of more than one word.
>
> When redirecting to a local URL, additional environment variables are
>   set so that the response can be further customized. **They are not sent
>   to external URLs**.

Use:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404_not_found.php
```